# how to fix circular dependency in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

> > foo has a bar type values and bar has foo type value as a meal, it is showing error that
>
> **[ts] Block-scoped variable 'foo' used before its declaration. [2448]**

```
const bar = {
            meal: foo,      //  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯!
            sweet: true,
            sassy: false,
};

const foo = {
            beer : 0,
            vodka : false,
            redwine: -1,
            taste: [bar]
};
```

Comment: why do have a constructor to initialize empty object for bar?

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with any types, just add one object to the other after it's all constructed:

```
const foo = {
  bear: 0,
  vodka: false,
  redwine: -1,
  taste: []
};

const bar = {
  meal: foo,
  sweet: true,
  sassy: false,
};

foo.taste.push(bar);
```

Comment: If I do like this then it is showing error  `[ts] Property 'taste' does not exist on type foo` on last line

Comment: Cannot reproduce that…

Comment: Thanks @deceze I did it by simply assigning fooType - `const foo: fooType = {
    bear : 0,
    vodka : false,
    redwine: -1,
    taste: []
};`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const bar = {
            sweet: true,
            sassy: false,
};

const foo = {
            beer : 0,
            vodka : false,
            redwine: -1,
            taste: []
};
bar.meal = foo;
foo.taste[0] = bar;
```

**EDIT 1:** Make the code compliant with the typing system

```
type barType = {
    sweet: boolean,
    sassy: boolean,
    meal: fooType
};
type fooType = {
    bear: number,
    vodka: boolean,
    redwine: number,
    taste: barType[]
};
const foo: fooType = {
    bear : 0,
    vodka : false,
    redwine: -1,
    taste: []
};
const bar: barType = {
    sweet: true,
    sassy: false,
    meal: foo
};
foo.taste[0] = bar;
```

Comment: it is showing `[ts] Property 'meal' does not exist on type '{ sweet: boolean; sassy: boolean; }'. [2339]`

Comment: Solve it this way: `const foo: {
    property: type
} = {property: value}`

Comment: Check **EDIT 1**

Comment: thanks I did in the same way we don't even require `foo.taste[0] = bar;`